# Find name of lambda argument passed in scala

Tags: scala, dsl

I am building a DSL using scala which will filter of data based on condition in a DSL.

Function of filter:

```
def filter(f: (Int) => (Int)) {
// find what is the name (age) of lambda passed
// query db with column name age and apply function f and return value

}
```

Using in DSL it as:

```
filter(  (age) => age > 10 )
```

I am not able to find a way to know that in DSL `age` is used, is there a way?

For the time being, I am passing the string as first argument like below:

```
filter( "age",   (age) => age > 10 )
```

and changed filter to take first argument as column name.

I want to simplify the DSL.

Comment: Can you add the actual implementation of your `filter` function ?

Comment: This will require a macro (if it's possible, which I don't know).

Comment: Wouldn't it be just as concise a DSL if you just call this as `filter("age", (_ > 10))`?

Comment: Implementation is very long, but to explain in context of question, filter will query db with column name 'age' which is of integer type and find all values which are less than 10 ( apply function defined in DSL) and return the last value. Basically I need know what column I need to apply the condition passed in DSL. Currently that's why I am passing column name as string in first argument

Comment: @ChrisMartin that underscore will hinder readability so I have designed as filter( "age" by { age => age > 10 } ). I have searched macros but not sure exactly how we can do that.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can currently obtain a name of the lambda instance's argument is by declaring a Scala Macro instead of a Scala method for `filter`. A macro will receive the abstract syntax tree of the lambda instead of the lambda itself, so it will be able to analyze the name of the lambda's arguments.

Here is a very minimal example of how to do that:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

object MyFilter {
  def filter(p: Int => Int): Unit = macro filterImpl
  def filterImpl(c: Context)(p: c.Expr[Int => Int]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._

    val Function(args, body) = p.tree
    val ValDef(mods, name, tp, rhs) = args(0)
    println(name)

    reify {
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Above, we first import the relevant packages to enable macros. Then, we define the *def macro* `filter` along with its implementation `filterImpl`. Finally, we implement the macro - we pattern match the tree of the argument into a `Function` tree, then take the first argument (`args(0)`), and finally pattern match the first argument into a `ValDef` tree to be able to extract the name.

You can read more about macros [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).

Comment: Thanks axel22.  I will try this. Looks like prefect solution. Any known issue like performance,etc. Also macros are still experimental I believe.

Comment: This is true - macros are still experimental. There should be no issues with performance, since the macro body is executed during compile time. The main downside is that you'll have to restructure your code across two modules (e.g. sbt projects) - one that defines the macro, and another that uses it, since macros cannot be invoked from the same compilation run that defines them.